# My css dropdown menu shows in the wrong place on internet explorer and firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Everything works great on Chrome and Safari but when I tried to check it using IE and FF the submenu menu shows in the left side of the main navigation. This is the website cedumilam.php.cs.dixie.edu. This is my CSS code:

```
#nav {
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 10;
    display: inline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav ul {
width:570;
margin:0px auto 2px auto;
text-align:center;}

#nav ul li{display: inline;
position:relative;
z-index:99;

}  

#nav li:hover { position: relative }
#nav li:hover > a { 
  color: #845343; 
  text-decoration:underline;
}

#nav li.sub:hover > a {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;        
}

#nav li a {

  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline;
}


#nav li ul { 
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: none;   
}

#nav li:hover ul {
  display:block; 
  position:absolute; 
}

#nav li ul {
  background: white;
  padding: 2px;      
}

#nav li ul li a, #nav li ul li a:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #000;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 0.95em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#nav li ul li a:hover { 
  color: #845343; 
  text-decoration: underline; 
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. Make sure that your HTML is always valid and you will have much less problems with CSS. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=cedumilam.php.cs.dixie.edu&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 Just as an example you are nesting elements incorrectly, you have missing end tags etc.

Comment: In the future please post code in your question/answer. Unless you can guarantee your linked website to stay the exact same and alive for a very long time...

Comment: Please povide a Fiddle. Just lookin at your css the       position:absolute; could be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work in Firefox, add this:

```
#nav li:hover ul {
    left: 0;
}
```

I think Firefox (and possibly Internet Explorer) interpret `position: absolute;` differently.

Sorry -- don't have Internet Explorer set up currently, so I can't test it there...

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/AQ39n/